# Обработка большого числа событий завязанных по времени

Tags: java, postgresql

Что есть и в чем проблема.
Пользователь может создавать некие события, каждое событие длится от 1 секунды до суток. В одно время у пользователя может быть только одно активное событие, остальные в очереди.
Я храню их в БД PostgreSQL, сам сервис написан на Java.
Я заношу в LinkedHashMap все события и раз в секунду пробегаю по очереди и обновляю в БД, что время для этого события сократило на секунду.
Как вы понимаете за 1 секунду имея больше 200-300К событий я не успею даже по очереди пробежаться.

Думаю не раз в секунду сохранять время в БД, а к примеру раз в минуту или тип того, но даже просто пройтись по мэпу в 200К элементов занимает больше секунды, а мне нужно четко чтоб событие завершилось через N секунд/минут/часов

Как кто решает такие проблемы?

Comment: Уточните условия, что за "некие события, каждое событие длится от 1 секунды до суток" в количестве сотен тысяч штук? Может быть вы в корне решаете не ту проблему.

Comment: Разные события, тут все верно, можно абстрактно подойти к этому, не привязываясь к сущностям)

Comment: Повторюсь, так как вы не ответили, а для вопроса это важно - **Уточните пожалуйста условия**, что за "некие события, каждое событие длится от 1 секунды до суток" в количестве сотен тысяч штук? **Может быть вы в корне решаете не ту проблему**.

Comment: А зачем пробегать по мапе, если активно может быть только одно событие? Какие условия задачи, что вообще нужно сделать? Мы не экстрасенсы, заглядывать в головы не умеем

Comment: Ок, смотрите, все знают онлайн игры где что-то нужно строить, и длится это N времени, после истечения времени обновляются некие данные(сущности), таких строек в игре оч много, вот ситуация такая-же!

Comment: Я думаю вам нужно смотреть в сторону паттерна Publisher/Subsriber. И при совершении какого-либо события (окончание строительства например) будет вызываться обработчик, который будет что-то делать, например сохранять данные в БД

Comment: а как узнать что произошло окончание события? тем более в пределах одной секунд

Comment: После окончания события вызывается обработчик. То есть идея в том, чтобы не вы контролировали их завершение, а сами сущности вызывали обработчики при наступлении события

Comment: Я это понимаю, просто понять не могу, чтоб событие вызывало обработчик, нужен некий таймер, варианта два хранить в map or list и бегать по нему, или для каждого задания создавать свой объект, а их как я говорил может быть 500К, что приведет к не хорошим последствиям. Я думал еще про шедулер в самой СУБД, но тоже не понятно справится или нет

Comment: @omicron почитайте за Publisher/Subscriber

Comment: Этим паттерном упрощается просто логика, создается объект и ждет(тем-же таймером к примеру) когда он выполнится и потом оповестит об этом, но как ни крути держать в памяти под 500К объектов, это не гуд( –

Answer (score 0):

Realtime обновление совершенно ни к чему.

Достаточно хранить время начала/конца события и, когда необходимо, сравнивать их с текущим временем.

Ведь Вы всегда можете получить то, что нужно, просто вычтя время начала из текущего времени, зачем же тратить ресурсы на поддержание этих данных?

Примеры запросов:

```
-- Сколько времени уже идут, сколько осталось для всех текущих событий
SELECT NOW()-start_time FROM events where NOW() between start_time and end_time
-- Получить необработанные события, которые истекли
SELECT * FROM events WHERE end_time < NOW() and processed = 0
```

Таким образом, Вы можете периодически запрашивать завершившиеся события и обновлять их статус.

---

*Теоретически(я не знаю точных условий Вашей задачи), Вы можете вместо базы данных использовать какой-нибудь сервер очередей(навроде RabbitMQ), который будет фильтровать события по статусу завершения, и/или уведомлять Вас (через sub/pub механизм) о изменившихся статусах.*

Comment: Да могу хранить время начало и когда должно закончиться. Вы хотите предложить в map хранить это время и по нему бегать или как? Ведь сервис то не узнает, что время истекло

Comment: `-- Сколько времени уже идут, сколько осталось для всех текущих событий
SELECT NOW()-start_time FROM events where NOW() between start_time and end_time
-- Получить необработанные события, которые истекли
SELECT * FROM events WHERE end_time < NOW() and processed = 0
Таким образом, Вы можете периодически запрашивать завершившиеся события и обновлять их статус`. Это вариант, но всеравно нужно его запускать каждую секунду) яж не могу при событии которое длится 3секунды, просрочить на еще несколько секунд